# RQDA - cannot load RGtk2.so

Tags: r, macos, rqda

I've been trying to solve this one for ages.
I want to use RQDA on my Mac. I have installed it (install.packages("RQDA")fine. But when I go to run it it asks if I need GTK+. I keep saying yes, but it fails.

```
library(RQDA)
```

> Loading required package: RSQLite
>
> Loading required package: gWidgetsRGtk2
>
> Loading required package: RGtk2
>
> Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
>     unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/RGtk2/libs/RGtk2.so':
>
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/RGtk2/libs/RGtk2.so, 6):
>
> Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libXinerama.1.dylib
>
> Referenced from: Library/Frameworks/GTK+.framework/Versions/2.24.X11/Resources/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.0.dylib
>
> Reason: image not found
>
> Need GTK+ ? (Restart R after installing)
>
> 1: Install GTK+
>
> 2: Do not install GTK+

I have checked my library path and found that the package is there but in the 3.3 version. It is sitting there "RGtk2.so".

```
libPaths()
```

> [1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library"

I have googled this to death. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After you have installed the RQDA package, and you call the library RQDA, be careful because a popup window raises asking for install RGtk2+ components. But that window can be hidden by your open aplications over the desktop. Look for the popup window and answer yes for install. Once is installed, won't be more problems.

Answer (score 0):

Install GTK from http://r.research.att.com/libs/GTK_2.24.17-X11.pkg. Make sure you have the latest XQuartz from https://www.xquartz.org/